# Advises needed on Zend Framework 2 modules and models architecture

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, architecture

I would like to start working with `Zend Framework 2` and need some guidance as to the architecture of the framework. I compared [Akrabat's ZF2 tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2-tutorial/) with it's [ZF1 equivalent](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) and the main difference I noticed so far seems to be the use of [modules](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/RFC+-+ZF2+Modules). I like the idea with modules as being independent and re-usable pieces of code and am thinking it could help segmenting my application and make it more maintainable. For instance I could have the following `URL => module` mapping:

```
http://example.org/products => Products module
http://example.org/services => Services module
http://example.org/oauth => Oauth module
[...]
```

What I'm confused about, is that some of my modules will share the same underlying database resources (e.g. both `Products` and `Services` use the same table for comments) and therefore the same database models. Accordingly, I'm wondering:

**Where should I put my database models when those are used by multiple modules?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following article: http://adam.lundrigan.ca/2011/09/module-dependencies-in-zf2/

You can create a third module (example: Base, Main) that is a dependency for the Products and Services modules, or you can add the Models to one of your modules and use that module as a dependency for the other one.

Module.php

```
/**
 * Get dependencies
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getDependencies()
{
    return array(
        'BaseModule' => array(
            'version' => '>=0.1.0',
            'required' => true
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: that could be a way to solve this problem indeed. Do you see any issue with putting all my basic database models (i.e. setters and getters) in a module such as `DatabaseModels` which as you explained would be a dependency for the other modules, and extend those database models within each corresponding module and put more advanced business logic into them?

Comment: I wouldn't put there all the models, only if they are common across all modules. Put models in their own module if possible.

Comment: You can do something similar to the following ZF2 modules [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) and [ZfcAcl](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAcl) both extend a base code from [ZfcBase](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase), but there's nothing specific of them in ZfcBase.